# Count number of times function with varying arguments executed, then reset count when ENTER key pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, counter, decorator, turtle-graphics

I would like to be able to count the number of times a defined function that **requires a varying argument** is executed, then **reset that counter to 0 every time the ENTER key is pressed**. I want to be able to utilize this action with the defined function below:

```
def draw(x):
    global drawing
    q.put(x)
    process = False
    drawingLock.acquire()
    if not drawing:
        process = True
        drawing = True
    drawingLock.release()
    if process:
        if not q.empty():
            x()
        drawingLock.acquire()
        drawing = False
        drawingLock.release()
```

This function is a `queue` that takes function arguments and executes them one by one, and the arguments for this function are functions that draw letters in the **turtle graphics** window. Additionally, this function gets called by a keypress of a certain letter that corresponds to the letter drawn. For example:

```
onkey(lambda: draw(draw_A), "a") 
# This draws an "A" in the Turtle Graphics window when "a" is pressed on the keyboard
# If multiple "A"s pressed, it draws them one by one
```

How would I count how many times this `draw()` function has been executed by the user in the turtle graphics window, and then reset it every time the ENTER key is pressed? I have tried creating a decorator for this, but the ones I have created does not return ANYTHING with turtle graphics, and does not seem to work with functions whose arguments can vary with those chosen by the user. Any help regarding this issue is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: You could solve this using a decorator, despite your failed attempts. BTW: Consider paths through your function where an exception is raised. In order to set a flag only in a certain scope, use either `try` and `finally` or use a so-called "context manager".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions allow attributes:

```
def draw(x):
    if not hasattr(draw, 'counter'):
         draw.counter = 0
    draw.counter += 1
    #  body
```

Catch the ENTER from the user:

```
def handle_enter():
    draw.counter = 0

onkey(handle_enter, 'Enter')
```

Find out how many times it has been called:

```
print('`draw` has been called {} times'.format(draw.counter))
```